# Data output over a period of time

Tags: java, android, file, date

There is a list of files that are created by the current date and time. I do not need to display all files, but only for the last 3 days. How can this be done?

[image: Screen shot of list of files]

```
listViewArchive = findViewById(R.id.listViewArchive);
        File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
        String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {
            theNamesOfFiles[i] = filelist[i].getName();
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theNamesOfFiles);
        listViewArchive.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am in this newbie, you can have a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this.

```java
ArrayList<String> theNameOfFiles = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
  long diff = (new Date().getTime() - filelist[i].lastModified()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

  if (diff <= 3)
    theNamesOfFiles.add(filelist[i].getName());
}
```

Comment: What is this for `theNameOfFiles`?
If you don't use it

Comment: You used it when you constructed the ArrayAdapter.
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theNamesOfFiles); <-- here

Comment: complains about `getTime`  error
`Cannot resolve method 'getTime()'`

Comment: updated the answer. lastModified() already returns a long added .getTime() by mistake there.

Comment: Per Johansson Can you tell us what `/ 60/60/24` means?

Comment: @Darsi I'm sorry for my poor example, I freehanded it so its untested. Was hoping it would get you idea how you could solve it. I should have taken more time. / 60 / 60 /25 was a way to get days 60 seconds per minute 60 minutes per hour 24 hours per day. But Looking back at my code you need / 1000 first since its milliseconds not seconds we work with. I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Parse your inputs as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd HHmmss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldtFile = LocalDateTime.parse( fileName , f ) ;
```

Compare to the current date time as seen your specific time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Get three days ago.

```
LocalDateTime ldtThreeDaysAgo = zdtNow.minusDays( 3 ).toLocalDateTime() ;  // Omits the context of a time zone, leaving only the date and time-of-day.
```

Compare each file's date-time.

```
if( ldtFile.isAfter( ldtThreeDaysAgo ) ) 
{
    … process 
}
```

All this has been covered many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: By the measure you suggested, it gives an error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/format/DateTimeFormatter;`
Complaining about this line `DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd HHmmss" ) ;`

Comment: @Darsi Fix your `import` statements.

Comment: which one and which one?
I can not understand.

Comment: @Darsi https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: if you meant it `import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;`
then he's already adding

Comment: @Darsi - Which version of Java are you using? `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` is available only with Java 8+.

Comment: @Darsi You probably need to reread the Android bits near the bottom of the answer. If the information there is not sufficient, I am sure we can point you to where more details can be found.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash java 8

Answer (score 0):

To check if the creation date of a File is between two dates you need to extract the creationDate. You can do that as follow:

```
      Path path = file.toPath();
      BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
      long creationTimeMs = attributes.creationTime().to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      // Do what you need to do with the creationTime
```